# couchdb python query document from view

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

Based on existing question
[Multiple CouchDB Document fetch with couchdb-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640054/multiple-couchdb-document-fetch-with-couchdb-python)

The question was:

> Blockquote: How to fetch multiple documents from CouchDB, in particular with couchdb-python?

One answer was:

> Blockquote: Easiest way is to pass a include_docs=True arg to Database.view. Each row of the results will include the doc

My question: how can i 'cast' or convert the returned document to my custom defined document.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As you're using Python I'd recommend [couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/). There you can either use the `MyDocument.view()` method or pass a `schema` parameter to `Database.view()`.