# bulk retrieve in CouchDB?

Tags: python, couchdb

I recently started to consider CouchDB to store a large list of dicts I manipulate in Python. Large in my case means about 20k elements.

I found out that the [`update()`](https://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.update) method is very fast in pushing my whole list in one HTTP call. It takes about 3 seconds, which is perfect for my case.

I also need (in a different script) to retrieve the whole content of this database and store it in a list of dicts. This is the opposite operation to the one above. 
Unfortunately the only way I found to do this is via

```
# db is the database opened following a couchdb.Server() call
mylist = list()
for id in db:
    mylist.append(db[id])
```

This takes 10 minutes as there is a call for each element of the loop.

- Is there an equivalent to `update()` to bulk-retrieve the contents of a database?
- or should I approach the retrieving part in a different, more efficient way?

Comment: The provided answer is perfect, I found in the meantime a duplicate and will flag my question (self-whipping style)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple CouchDB Document fetch with couchdb-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640054/multiple-couchdb-document-fetch-with-couchdb-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get every document is to issue a request to `_all_docs` and pass `include_docs=true`.

`_all_docs` will get the basic details (_id, revision) of all documents in the database. `include_docs` causes the full documents to be included in the response.

```
/mydatabase/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

If you need something more subtle than returning entire documents (e.g. returning a single scalar value for each document) then you need to look into [views](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html).

Comment: speaking in context of couchdb-python, you need to call `db.view("_all_docs", include_docs=True)` or better `db.iter_view("all_docs", 100, include_docs=True)` to not fail with OOM error since this call will return you mostly whole database data.